# How to train Naive Bayes Classifier for only 1 class

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, naivebayes

Suppose I want to know how much religious a person is i.e. rather than classifying him as `religious` or `non-religious` I want to know the probability of him being religious. So, I have created a simple `Naive Bayes` classifier using `nltk` toolkit. But It doesn't seem to work, I am getting probability of 100% for both test samples.

> Train Set Size = 5
>
> 1.0
>
> 1.0

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

dataPos = [('god jesus god church'), ('buddha enlightenment love god'),
        ('jesus love krishna'), ('Hare krishna Hare Krishna love'),
        ('god jesus church love')]

def create_word_features(words):
    useful_words = [word for word in words if word not in stopwords.words("english")]
    my_dict = dict([(word, True) for word in useful_words])
    return my_dict

pos_views = []
for item in dataPos:
    words = item.split(' ')
    pos_views.append((create_word_features(words), "positive"))

train_set = pos_views[:]

print( 'Train Set Size = %d' %(len(train_set)) )

# Train
classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

# Testing Sample 1
person1 = '''
Love god krishna jesus
'''
words = word_tokenize(person1)
words = create_word_features(words)
prob_dist = classifier.prob_classify(words)
print(prob_dist.prob("positive"))

# Testing Sample 2
person2 = '''
I hate god hate
'''
words = word_tokenize(person2)
words = create_word_features(words)
prob_dist = classifier.prob_classify(words)
print(prob_dist.prob("positive"))
```

I believe the problem is of having only one class, but that's how I want to train the classifier can anybody tell me how to fix this.

Comment: You need two classes. And you need examples for both of them in your training set.

Comment: @mercator I know how to do it with two class. I want to know how can we do it for 1 class

Comment: Try solving Bayes' rule with only one class. The class prior `P(C) = 1` because all your documents are in that class. All features you've seen are in that class too, so `P(w|C) = P(w)`. Maybe you're looking more for a document similarity measure?

Comment: @mercator Ok that means for naive bayes we need atleast 2 classes

Comment: http://homepage.tudelft.nl/n9d04/thesis.pdf